# Create specific view for all categories

Tags: views, 8

I have a list of Categories defined that all have specific URL aliases defined. I'm trying to set up views for those specific feeds.

For example, if I have categories

`cats`, `dogs`, `fish` (with aliases `/cats` `/dogs/`/fish`) I'm trying to set a view for those pages.

I know I can create a view and say `Show Content of Type All tagged with:___` but I believe that works off tags, not categories.

If I try to say `Show Taxonomy Terms of type Category` then it looks like it's just a list of `cats` `dogs` `fish`

Is there a nice way to set up what I'm trying to do, or am I better off using tags instead?

Comment: Assuming "categories" is a taxonomy vocabulary and "cats," "dogs," and "fish" are all terms in that vocabulary, you can use your first guess and grab all items tagged with one of those animals.

Comment: Okay, so I would need to create 3 different views? There's no easy way for me to create one over-arching category view so that any posts which are tagged with a category will appear a specific way?

Comment: Yes you can do that with contextual filters.  Look under admin > structure > views at the view 'Taxonomy term', which is an example you could readily copy.

Comment: @stevekeiretsu Oh wow, just copied that and it worked perfectly, thank you. I had tried messing around with that view once already but didn't realize that it was already set up to be what I wanted and I just had to change the `Show` section.